# EventReciever as SandBox Solution

Tags: event-receivers, sandbox-solution, resources

I am having an Event receiver as sandbox solution to perform certain action on item Added to the list. Basically it is creating a sub-site on item added using custom template.
Problem i am facing is every time i am deploying the wsp, it is eating up resources and unable to create the site. Creating the sub-site code is taking too long time and resource quota get exceed from its limit.
How Can i improve the performance of the solution.Reading through several articles i found instantiating the `SPWeb, SPSite, SPListItem` cause the issue. But in my solution i tried to obtain these object through "Properties".

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
SPWeb oWeb = properties.OpenWeb();
string owebAddress = oWeb.Title;
SPWebCollection webcoll = oWeb.Webs;
SPWeb newWeb = null;
String url = "C" + prop.ListItem["ID"].ToString();
string currentTemplate = getCurrentTemplate("UPCST", prop.OpenWeb());
newWeb =webcoll.Add(url,ClientName, url, 1033, currentTemplate, false, false);  // this line is taking too long time.
newWeb.Update();
oWeb.Update();
}

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subsite in sandbox code is just too much for the sandbox code service to handle. You don't have enough control over the resource and timeout limits. You might get it to a point where it seems to work, but it will intermittently crash and cause you major headaches. I recommend you find a different way to implement the functionality you need - a workflow, perhaps.

http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2012/02/sp2010-online-timeouts-in-the-sandbox/

From MSDN:

> If you need to use long-running processes to deliver your
>   functionality, a sandboxed solution is unlikely to be the best choice.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx

Comment: Is that any unreleased objects in the code is stimulating the issue.?

Comment: I found Timer Service Recycle timer job in the background which is responsible  for cleaning up the daily usage resources by the sandbox solution .In my case i found that timer job is not running for the context of my site collection . Can you please help me to activate that job.

Comment: And I noticed that the resource Daily quota is also not getting referesh / clear for the next day .? No Idea why?

Comment: When I said it will cause you major headaches, this is exactly what I was talking about.